# A couple of questions regarding gpu/igpu/apu

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade, gpu

I am running Intel HD5500 as my gpu. Am I understanding correctly in that this is an IGPU, meaning that my gpu is integrated into my cpu as one unit? In addition, is an IGPU and an APU the same thing? They appear both synonymous and as a separate entity at the same time.

If my hardware is an IGPU/APU, can I upgrade in anyway?

Trying to do something such as play Batllefiel Hardline on my computer as well as simply learn all of these things.

If it is not possible for me to upgrade the Intel HD5500 on my laptop, can I use a discrete gpu OUTSIDE of my laptop, but connected in some way sot hat I could have an efficient computer to play games if I wanted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> In addition, is an IGPU and an APU the same thing?

Intel does not have any APU products on the market at this time.  APU is something AMD came up with to describe a product that had one of their CPU and GPU integrated together.

> If my hardware is an IGPU/APU, can I upgrade in anyway?

You are thinking about getting a laptop, so you would not be able to upgrade the CPU, which also means you would be stuck with the HD5500 for the lifetime of the device.

> Trying to do something such as play Batllefield Hardline on my
>   computer as well as simply learn all of these things.

Just look up the system requirements of the program you want to run.  Determine if the HD5500 will be powerful enough to run said program.

> If it is not possible for me to upgrade the Intel HD5500 on my laptop,
>   can I use a discrete gpu OUTSIDE of my laptop, but connected in some
>   way sot hat I could have an efficient computer to play games if I
>   wanted?

If you want hardware that you can upgrade don't get a laptop.  There are very few external graphic card solutions, almost none of them, would be better then the HD5500 honestly.

Comment: Not quite accurate, there are thunderbolt eGPUs now that perform at near PCIE performance and can work well. But they arent cost effective. @airkeyahguh you bought a motorbike when you needed a truck, that isnt a gaming machine. If you want to game, save some money, sell it and buy something with a dedicated GPU (it will cost more).

Comment: @Linef4ult - The only "Thunderbolt" GPUs I have seen are hacks that require a stationary laptop.  So Lucid has an actual product.  The problem is its 3 generations old "their external box integrates an AMD Radeon 6700 chip" hence my statement, that it would be slower then a HD5500.  I found zero stores with it.  Says a great deal about the price

Comment: Thanks guys, it looks like you're right and I will be looking into an upgrade soon. I'm not sure what to get, but I really like Lenovo ThinkPads, but it seems like most of this still use IGPU's, except the $2.3K+ models. 

So just to clarify, APU's and IGPU's ARE essentially the same thing, other than the fact that AMD calls their graphics that are integrated into the CPU an "APU," correct? And IGPU is just a more general industry term.

Have a great day!!